# Maximize memory for file cache or memory-based file system on Windows?

Tags: windows, file, caching, io

I have an application which needs to create many small files in maximum performance (less than 1% of them may be read later), and I want to avoid using asynchronous file API to keep the simplicity of my code. The size of total files written cannot be pre-determined, so I figured that to achieve maximum performance, I would need:

1.Windows to utilize all unused RAM for cache (especially for file writes), with no regard of relibility or other issues. If I have more than 1GB of unused RAM and I create one million of 1KB files, I expect Windows to report "DONE" immediately, even if it has written nothing to disk yet.

OR

2.A memory-based file system backed by real on-disk file system. Whenever I write files, it should first write everything in memory only, and then update on-disk file system in background. No delay in synchronous calls unless there isn't enough free memory. Note it's different from tmpfs or RAM disk implementations on Windows, since they require fixed amount of memory and utilize page file when there isn't enough RAM.

For option 1, I have tested VHD files - while it does offer as high as 50% increase of total performance under some configurations, it still does flushing-to-disk and cause writing to wait unnecessarily. And it appears there is no way I can disable journaling or further tweak the write caching behavior.....

For option 2, I have yet found anything similar..... Do such things exist?

Comment: perhaps you should rethink your design. if <1% of the files are reader later, perhaps you should redesign the system so that the other 99% are not created/written in the first place.

Comment: This reads like a classic XY question.  Where the answer to X surely is "use a database instead".  Y is "the cache granularity is more than a kilobyte.  Just buy more RAM".

Comment: Marc B: no, the files are meant to be read by others. Only 1% is read by my own app later (so there is a problem with dependency if I'm to make all write async)

Comment: Hans Passant: unfortunately the output format cannot change. It's actually the interface of the app (to other systems). It has nothing to do with cache granularity - I have several times more memory than the sum of all output data and other related files, but windows appears to force flush (or update journal?) on file close and other operations, which I suspect may be the reason that writing them to vhd is much faster than writing to real disk.